# Move a rectangle using angles

Tags: c#, graphics, angle, drawrectangle

I need to move a rectangle using angles. Actually I want to change the direction of my moving rectangle when it reaches the location I have given in my code in if statement!

I just need the way I can find out how to move my rectangle at 60, 30, 60, 120, 150, 270 degrees!

Suppose that if

```
          circle.Y>=this.Height-80
```

See this:
[image]

I really actually need to change the direction of rectangle movement using angles! so that at certain location reaches I can change the rectangle direction according to angle of my own choice!
such that:

```
if(circle.Y>=this.Height-80)
    move in the direction of 90 degrees

if(circle.X>=this.Width-80)
    move in the direction of 60 degree
```

as you can see in the screen shot!

What I have been trying is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Rectangle circle;
    double dx = 2;
    double dy = 2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        circle = new Rectangle(10, 10, 40, 40);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Refresh();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), circle);
    }

    private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        circle.X += (int)dx;
        circle.Y += (int)dy;
        if (circle.Y>=this.Height-80)
        {
            dy = -Math.Acos(0) * dy/dy; //here i want to change the direction of circle at 90 degrees so that it should go up vertically straight with same speed
        }
        this.Refresh();
    }
}
```

The Problem is that I have been trying changing my conditions to:

```
dy = -Math.Asin(1) * dy;
dx = Math.Acos(0) * dx ;
```

but in both cases nothing is happening and the direction remains same!
I just want to move the circle in inverted upward direction at 90 degrees when it reach at

```
circle.Y>=this.Height-80
```

Comment: Even if it's an assignment, we still help.  It's the effort you put into the code that matters to us.

Comment: the answer would remain same dear see dx=dy=2; and though dx/dy=dy/dx=1;

Comment: @user3411946 - Don't put extra code that achieves nothing and only serves to confuse us.  There is obviously no purpose to `* dy/dy`.  Please change the code to reflect what you are actually trying to achieve.  Or explain it in words, and we can tell you what the calculation should be.

Comment: yes it is because my rectangle changes the direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to draw the rectangle again to some image for it to display. I created this code for moving and drawing rectangle on `pictureBox1`, using your already defined `circle`-rectangle:

**Moving the rectangle:**

```
public void MoveRectangle(ref Rectangle rectangle, double angle, double distance)
{
   double angleRadians = (Math.PI * (angle) / 180.0);
   rectangle.X = (int)((double)rectangle.X - (Math.Cos(angleRadians) * distance));
   rectangle.Y = (int)((double)rectangle.Y - (Math.Sin(angleRadians) * distance));
}
```

**Drawing the rectangle and displaying it in the `PictureBox`:**

```
public void DrawRectangle(Rectangle rectangle)
{
   Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
   using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
   {
      g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
      g.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), rectangle);
   }
   pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}
```

**Demo it with a button click:**

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MoveRectangle(ref circle, 90, 5);
   DrawRectangle(circle);
}
```

Comment: well I don't need the whole code but i got super ideas from your answer bounty awarded thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Math.Asin(1) * dy is a constant value. Thus, you should use, for example, an instance variable that increments in each Tick of your timer.

...And **dy/dy* is irrelevant.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Rectangle circle;
    double dx = 2;
    double dy = 2;
    acum=0; //the new variable
```

...

```
private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        circle.X += (int)dx;
        circle.Y += (int)dy;
        if (circle.Y>=this.Height-300)
        {
            dy = -Math.Acos(acum); 
            acum+=1; //your accumulator
        }
        this.Refresh();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

acos and asin are the inverse of sin and cos so the output of those two functions is an angle (usually in radians). This makes the code incorrect.

I strongly suggest that you read up on vector and matrix maths as using Euler angles can get quite messy.

So, you will have a position vector P and a movement vector M and the current position is:

```
 P' = P + M.t
```

where t is time, P is the original position and P' is the current position.

Then, when you want to change direction, you create a rotation matrix and multiply the movement vector M by this rotation matrix.

The advantage here is that you can step from a 2D system to a 3D system by adding a Z component to your vectors and increasing the size of your matrices.

Comment: Actually, in your example, the rotation matrix is not needed, the new movement vector will be (0,1) assuming upwards is +ve y.

Comment: so how can i really achieve this